# Assign if undefined

Tags: javascript

Is there any shorter way to do this?

```
if (!someVar) {
    someVar = defaultVar;
}
```

I know this:

```
someVar = someVar || defaultVar;
```

But I don't like `someVar` duplicating here. Any other ideas?

Comment: That is bad practice, because it will reassign someVar if it is falsy, not just if it is undefined.

Comment: No. You need it once for the condition and once for the assignment

Comment: @Asad: No - it depends on the expected type of `somevar`. For objects this is the default practice, for booleans you of course would check for `typeof someVar`

Comment: and integers, and strings, and basically anything nullable. of course you might have circumstances where you are guaranteed to recieve either an object or nothing, in which case I guess this is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, javascript doesn't support the `||=` way, so the below is the shortest.

```
someVar = someVar || defaultVar;
```